# Set mic quality?

Tags: 16.04, microphone, msi

When using this mic in Windows I always first had to go to "Capture Devices" and set the quality for the mic to "Studio Quality". Otherwise it would sound really high pitched. Like a smurf. Is there any way to set mic quality in Ubuntu?

MSI B85M-E45
Ubuntu 16.04.3

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu has conventional tools to manage sound devices, as speakears, headphones and mics.

**Alsamixer**

It's a terminal-based tool directly attached to alsatools. You must open a terminal window and type `alsamixer`:

[image]

Here you must press <kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>right</kbd> to go trough components, <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> to change levels and <kbd>M</kbd> to mute/unmute them.

If your computer has more than one sound device, switch among them with <kbd>F6</kbd>

**Pulseaudio Volume Control (pavucontrol)**

pavucontrol is a GUI-based sound controller for alsa. You can install it by `sudo apt install pavucontrol`. It gives you a better control of sources for your sound devices, changing best profiles to improve sound performance.

[image]

Comment: On increasing the latency offset the quality became better.